# Adding both a timer and subscription to the executor seems to cause error_loop() to run

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I'm working with micro-ros and I'm trying to add in my script a timer and subscription, but always it cause an error in error_loop when it’s execued. It's posible to have them both in the same script?.

> RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, 1, &allocator));

> RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_subscription(&executor, &subscriber, &msg_cmd_vel, &subscription_callback, ALWAYS));

> RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_timer(&executor, &timer));

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384775/adding-both-a-timer-and-subscription-to-the-executor-seems-to-cause-error_loop()-to-run/) by [jarain78](https://answers.ros.org/users/36067/jarain78/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are initing the executor with 1 handle (check the 3th argument) and then adding a sub and a timer.

Just do:

`RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, 2, &allocator));`

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarain78](https://answers.ros.org/users/36067/jarain78/) on 2021-08-23**:
Hi Pablo, thank you for replying, your suggestion has solved my problem.